# How should I view the balanced product of two sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We now define complete parenthesization by induction as follows:

(1)A list of length 1 is completely parenthesized.

(2)A list of length $n>1$ is completely parenthesized by specifying a $k$ with $1\le k<n$ and
a complete parenthesization of the sublists $(s_1,\dots,s_k)$ and $(s_{k+1},\dots,s_n)$.

We define the set $V_n$ consists of all completely parenthesized lists of the elements of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ in any order.

Now consider $V_n\times_{\Sigma_n}X^n$ where if $(j_1,\dots, j_n)$ is a completely parenthesized list, $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ is an n-tuple in $X$, and $\sigma\in \Sigma_n$, then $$((j_1,\dots, j_n)\cdot\sigma,(x_1,\dots, x_n))\sim((j_1,\dots, j_n),\sigma\cdot (x_1,\dots, x_n)) $$ where the right and left action are permuting around the elemets. I know that $V_n\times_{\Sigma_n}X^n$ has cardinality equal to the cardinality of the vertices of the nth associahedron times the cardinality of X to the nth power but it is not a good idea to think of it as that I believe. What should I view it as?

I am really wanting something with the same structure as  $$V_n\times_{\Sigma_n}X^n.$$

Comment: One thing you can say is that this is in canonical bijection with the parenthesized expressions of length $n$ in $X$, or in other words the elements of length $n$ in the free magma on $X$.

Comment: It's the same kind of thing as the free group on $X$, but instead of being the "most general" group generated by elements of $X$, it is the "most general" magma. In concrete terms, it can be seen as the set of parenthesized expressions (of any length) in $X$.

Comment: Your construction looks like it comes from the theory of operads, namely the symmetric operad of magmas (not sure how it is officially called). You should check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad if you're not aware of what that is.

Comment: Well let $V$ be the operad where $V(k)=V_k$. Consider $EV$ where $E$ is left adjoint to the set-of-objects functor. Then the algebras over $EV$ are precisely the symmetric monoidal categories with strict unit and the algebra morphisms are strict functors. This is a categoriccal operad with a $\Sigma$-free action. By a paper of Elmendorf there exists a category of generalized multicategories associated to this operad. I needed this construction because it requires a source map from a st of morphisms to the monad with which this construction is concerned applied to a set of morphisms.

Comment: I just needed to see what the monad precisely was. Thanks for the boost.

Comment: So, yeah this was for a seperate operad.

Comment: But I do have a question for you now. Is the disjoint union of a operad of sets at each level usually a monad?

Comment: You might want to think of a more descriptive title for your question.

Comment: I assume $\Sigma_n$ is the $n$-th symmetric group.  What are the definitions of $\sigma\cdot(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\cdot \sigma$?  Are they $\left(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\cdots,x_{\sigma(n)}\right)$ and $\left(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},x_{\sigma^{-1}(2)},\cdots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}\right)$, respectively?

Comment: That is correct.